# $f(z) = \frac{a_0+a_1z^1+...+a_{n-1} z^{n-1}}{b_0+b_1z^1+...+b_n z^n}, b_n \neq 0$. Show that sum of residues at its poles is $\frac{a_{n-1}}{b_n}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Assume that the zeroes of the denominator are simple. Show that the sum of residues at its poles is equal to $\frac{a_{n-1}}{b_n}$

Hi everyone, Iam not able to start the above problem. Hint needed. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hint: Since you tagged this (complex-analysis) (and rightfully), which important theorem did you see when studying this subject?

Comment: Hi@Did I have studied Rouche's theorem, Cauchy residue theorem. Cauchy integral theorem and theroems about polynomials and rational functions.

Comment: Right, and one these fits perfectly, no?

Comment: @Did Taking a circular contour of a large radius, as R -> infinity it includes all the poles of f(z) and the sum of residues is given by limit of zf(z) as z->infinity. Am i correct in saying so?

Comment: "the sum of residues is given by limit of zf(z) as z->infinity" Huh? Which theorem would that be?

Comment: @Did sum of residues of all poles including infinity is zero. residue at inifinity is given by lim z->infinty = -zf(z). so the sum of residues at all poles zf(z)

Comment: "sum of residues of all poles including infinity is zero" Please specify the hypothesis needed here. "so the sum of residues at all poles zf(z)" The sentence does not parse (a verb is lacking?). (Amusingly, the answer you accepted 19 hours ago is not based on the result you are invoking in the comment you posted 18 hours ago.)

Comment: Hi @Did yes you are correct, when i accepted the solution, I just solved as he suggested and got the answer. Then after the readings in the book, images of which I have posted, I thought if i can say so, as u asked which theorem fits it perfectly. I didn't get which theorem it is, so posted my assumption, Iam not saying I was right as I dont have requisite knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $z_i$ be the poles of $f$. Decompose $f$ in simple fractions:
$$f(z)=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{A_i}{z-z_i}$$

The residues of $f$ are the $A_i$. Compute the limit of $zf(z)$ as $|z|\to \infty$ by two manners.